# Switching from tensorflow on python 3.6 to python 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my first question on stackoverflow, please bear with me as I will do my best to provide as much info as possible.

I have a windows 10, 6-bit processor.  My end goal is to use keras within spyder.  The first thing I did was update python to 3.6 and install tensorflow, which seemed to work.  When I attempted to get keras, however, it wasn't working, and I read that keras worked on python 3.5.  I successfully installed keras on python 3.5, which automatically installed theano as the backend.

But now I have two spyder environments, one running off of python 3.5, one off of 3.6.  The 3.5 reads keras but doesn't go through with any modules because it cannot find tensorflow.  The 3.6 can read tensorflow, but cannot find keras.

Please let me know what you would recommend.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtualenv with python 3.5 installed.

I dealt with this same issue, using Jupyter Notebook. Didn't understand why you would even need a virtualenv until I learned from this roadblock.

Full details on installing and setting up a virtualenv can be found here:
http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

Answer (score 0):

Odd, the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) say that TF only supports Python 3.5 on Windows. I would uninstall TF with `pip uninstall tensorflow` (if you installed it with `pip` to begin with) using `pip` from your Python 3.6 path, then re-install (`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`) making sure that you are running `pip` from your Python 3.5 path.

Comment: I installed tensorflow on the 3.5 path as you suggested, and found a "tensorflow" folder in my Anaconda3\env path.  I dragged it into the myenv folder.  When I attempt to run keras.layers in spyder, it gets a little further, but now says it cannot find the module "tensorflow.python."  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean into the `myenv` folder? Are you running this in a virtual environment? Did you install tensorflow from within your virtual environment if so?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with my tensorflow's installation too.
I personnaly used anaconda to solve the problem.
After installing anaconda (Maybe uninstall the old one if you already have one), launch an anaconda prompt and input `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`, afther that, you must activate it with `activate tensorflow`.
Once it's done, you have to install tensorflow on your python 3.5.
For that, use:

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`
for cpu version

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` for gpu version

You now have the r1.2 version of tensorflow.

Then, just use `pip install keras` and keras will be installed.

Now, all you have to do is launch anaconda navigator, select tensorflow on the scrolling menu and launch spyder/jupyter.
You can now use Keras with a tensorflow backend in Python 3.5

Hope it helped someone ! (It take me so much time to find it by myself)

Comment: When I tried this, the command prompt tells me that https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.  Any ideas how to get past that?

Comment: It seems like the python version is not the good one.
Try this : `python --version` in your anaconda prompt after activating tensorflow (not sure if it change something but I do it all the time to get sure). If it's not a python 3.5 use `conda install python=3.5`

Comment: It tells me I'm using python 3.5.3.